# How to vectorize the following operation in matlab?

Tags: image-processing, vectorization

I want to vectorize the array : **final**

I made this code to make red the pixels of the array **I**

**bw** : black and white array

**I** : the original image

**final** : the array i want to store the values

```
for i = 1:sz1
    for j = 1:sz2
        if (bw(i,j)==1) 
           final(i,j,1)=255;
           final(i,j,2)=0;
           final(i,j,3)=0;
       else
            final(i,j,1)=I(i,j,1);
           final(i,j,2)=I(i,j,2);
           final(i,j,3)=I(i,j,3);
        end
    end
end
```

I don't want to have any for/loops.
Have anyone an idea?
Thanks

Comment: Search for “logical indexing”. You’ll find lots of examples similar to what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Solved it:

```
final=I;
final(bw==1)=255;
```